# Xcode Resizing iPhone 5 app for iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, layout, screen

I have successfully created and tested my iOS app for iPhone 5 screen size. I have disabled Auto Layout in my storyboard because I have created custom subviews. What is the easiest way to make it compatible with older device screen sizes (like iPhone 4/4s)? Do I need to re-enable Auto Layout? What is the traditional method of making iOS apps with dynamic screen sizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use property autoResizingMask of UIView to do declare the autoresizing for views you want it changed dynamically.